# What's the best way for a website to detect payments from green addresses?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, green-address

Does any proven third party code exist for this?

Edit*

To be more specific, what I haven't been able to find out is how to get the sender's bitcoin address when receiving a transaction. As far as I know, bitcoind doesn't have a command that shows the prev_out hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is now possible to determine the list of addresses that sent a transaction using the raw transaction [JSON-RPC API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) calls that were released with bitcoind and bitcoin-qt version 0.7. The pseudo-code to accomplish this is:

```
txid = <relevant transaction id>
addresses = []
raw_tx = decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(txid))
for(input in raw_tx['vin']) {
  input_raw_tx = decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(input['txid']))
  addresses.push(input_raw_tx['vout'][input['vout']]['scriptPubKey']['addresses'][0])
}
```

Once you have the list of sending addresses stored in the `addresses` array, you can compare these addresses to a list of pre-approved green addresses. In most cases, you should expect there to only be a single unique address in the `addresses` array.

In order to get a list of suitable green addresses, you could hard-code it into your application, or you could use a dynamic source, such as [Deepbit's JSON feed](https://deepbit.net/green.json). This feed however, is notably missing [Mt. Gox's Green Address](https://blockchain.info/address/1LNWw6yCxkUmkhArb2Nf2MPw6vG7u5WG7q)

Answer (score 2):

As of right now there's only two green addresses, MtGox and Instawallet. A simple string comparison would suffice. In the near future a dictionary would be the way to go and after that there'll most likely be a service that offers a "green address check".

TL;DR: Code is trivial right now. Proven code will come when it's needed but will also be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Deepbit provides provides a JSON page with a list of popular green addresses:

http://deepbit.net/green.json

Index that, then as lodewijk suggested string matching should suffice.